# Access elements in Polymer dom-repeat template

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to access elements created inside a dom-repeat template so I can modify them programatically.

```
<google-map id="map">
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="markers" items="{{items}}">
        <google-map-marker latitude="item.latitude" longitude="item.longitude">
        </google-map-marker>
    </template>
</google-map>
```

Is there anything that I can do to get an array of the google-map-markers within the template? I couldn't find a solution to this problem anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating and inserting the markers programatically.

HTML:

```
<google-map id="map">
</google-map>
```

JavaScript:

```
for (var i=0; i<this.items.length; i++) {
    var marker = document.createElement('google-map-marker');
    marker.latitude = this.items[i].latitude;
    marker.longitude = this.items[i].longitude;
    //any additional operations that are needed
    Polymer.dom(this.$.map).appendChild(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map

the markers property returns the read-only array of markers on the map.